# How can I prevent FetchRequest to observe changes in relationships?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

In my app I have two CoreData entities with a relationship of one to many: People -> Subject

I'm rendering People's name using a List

```swift
struct PeopleListView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
            entity: People.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \People.updatedAt, ascending: false)]
        ) var people: FetchedResults<People>
     
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(people) { person in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PersonView(person: person)) {
                        Text(person.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Then on PersonView:

```swift
struct PersonView: View {
    var person: Person
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context;
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                self.person.subjects.insert(Subject(context: self.context))
            }, label: { Text("Add Subject") })
            ForEach(Array(person.subjects)) { subject in
                Text(subject.name)
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

As soon as I tap on the button for "Add Subject" I get the following warning:

```
[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView: 0x7f8e0e822800; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003f0ed30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000315a720>; contentOffset: {0, -140}; contentSize: {414, 748}; adjustedContentInset: {140, 0, 34, 0}; dataSource: <_TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff2c9c8ad419ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___: 0x7f8e0cc0e070>>
```

I think my problem actually is that as soon as I add a subject to a person, the FetchRequest "gets notified" and re-draws `PeopleListView` while I'm on `PersonView`.

I would really appreciate a proper solution for this issue, I guess there should be a way to say to `FetchRequest` to not listen to changes on the relationships, but I couldn't find one.

I have also though on other solutions like proxying the subject list and only "inject them" when I go back to the PeopleListView, but that sounds awful.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no UITableView in your code so the origin of the error is unclear but nonetheless one idea is to not use the property wrapper `@FetchRequest` and use your fetch request manually instead

Comment: As far as I understand, the UITableView is generated behind the scenes on SwiftUI as part of the List view. I have just found that FetchRequest has a constructor FetchRequest(withRequest:) where you can specify a custom NSRequest, but so far no luck on not observing the subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need to avoid fetching relationships during fetch main entities, here is possible approach using custom `NSFetchRequest` combined with SwiftUI `FetchRequest`.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct PeopleListView: View {

    @FetchRequest
    var people: FetchedResults<People>

    init() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<People> = People.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        request.includesSubentities = false             // << here !!

        _people = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    }

    // ... other code
```

Comment: Thanks! I've selected this one as the correct answer since it does what the question ask for. But the actual solution to my issue is the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue I was having is that a couple of records inside People didn't have an id (which I'm using to make them `identifiable`) and by default I'm just assigning a new id if none is defined.

Therefore, everytime I added a subject, SwiftUI re-render the view and find that the people has changed (since they have a different id) causing the observed issue.

So, the way to solve the specific problem I was facing, is having a proper id (or specifying one on the id argument of ForEach view)